# Monitor Mongo using MMS to see current Op

Tags: mongodb

We have enabled authentication and we are on Mongo 2.4.8.
Please advise if there is any method to view currentOp() or currently running queries using MMS

Answer (score 0):

MMS is not real time monitoring system, MMS agent sends usage statistics once per minute. So it is not possible to see currently running queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot - MMS uses an agent to read from your mongoDB instances. It polls on a regular basis for stats. You cannot use it to run db commands.

You can, however, view the logs from your instances if you enable it - Under the Logs tab under Hosts. If you've enabled Profiling for your instance you can set MMS up to pull the profile data which will include recent database operations - however be aware that turning on Profiling can have a performance impact: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/